# Explaining post-increment in C#

Tags: c#, post-increment

I have some code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        j = j++;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

Why answer is 0 ?

Comment: Such code *must* come from academia. Absurd.

Comment: I thought that answer will be 10

Comment: No, because the value of j is taken into intermediate result, variable j is incremented and THEN is intermediate result assigned to j.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - You should post that as an answer. The best answer so far, btw.

Comment: There are at least half a dozen similar questions.

Comment: Nikola has already explained the why, to get the expected result the line is just `j++;` not `j = j++;`

Comment: Why did you think you wouldn't get zero?

Comment: Best code ive seen so far. Why not just use `j += 1` ? or `j++` ?

Comment: @harold One could think it's undefined behavior. In other languages such as c/c++ the result would be undefined. Even in C# where it's well defined, many people misunderstand them since there are a couple of subtle points one can easily get wrong.

Comment: @harold: I imagine the OP doesn't expect 0 he assumes that j=j++ is equivalent to j=j followed by j=j+1. This would lead to j=10 after 10 cycles of the for loop.

Comment: I suppose that's all very possible, but I was rather hoping to get the OP's reason, to better to address the misunderstanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the way the [++ increment works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx). [The order of operations is explained in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363) This can be seen here (somebody please correct me if I am reading the spec on this one wrong :)):

```
int j = 2;
//Since these are value objects, these are two totally different objects now
int intermediateValue = j;
j = 2 + 1
//j is 3 at this point
j = intermediateValue;
//However j = 2 in the end
```

Since it is a value object, the two objects (`j` and `intermediateValue`) at that point are different. The old j was  incremented, but because you used the same variable name, it is lost to you. I would suggest reading up on the difference of [value objects versus reference objects](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx), also.

If you had used a separate name for the variable, then you would be able to see this breakdown better.

```
int j = 0;
int y = j++;
Console.WriteLine(j);
Console.WriteLine(y);
//Output is 
// 1
// 0
```

If this were a reference object with a similar operator, then this would most likely work as expected. Especially pointing out how only a new pointer to the same reference is created.

```
public class ReferenceTest
{
    public int j;
}

ReferenceTest test = new ReferenceTest();
test.j = 0;
ReferenceTest test2 = test;
//test2 and test both point to the same memory location
//thus everything within them is really one and the same
test2.j++;
Console.WriteLine(test.j);
//Output: 1
```

Back to the original point, though :)

If you do the following, then you will get the expected result.

```
j = ++j;
```

This is because the increment occurs first, then the assignment.

However, ++ can be used on its own. So, I would just rewrite this as

```
j++;
```

As it simply translates into

```
j = j + 1;
```

Comment: The order of operations is not correct. The assignment happens after the increment using a stored value. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363

Comment: There is no difference between value and reference types in this context.

Comment: @fgb Hrmm, I guess I never dug into the order of operations. I will update my answer

Comment: @CodeInChaos You are correct, however I think part of the confusion with this could be resolved with a proper understanding of value versus reference objects

Comment: @fgb Feel free to take a look and verify that I wrote the order up properly :)

Comment: @JustinPihony Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

As the name says, post-increment increments after the value has been used

```
y = x++;
```

According to the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) this is equivalent to

```
temp = x;
x = x + 1;
y = temp;
```

Applied to your original problem it means that `j` remains the same after these operations.

```
temp = j;
j = j + 1;
j = temp;
```

---

You can also use pre-increment, which does the opposite

```
x = x + 1;
y = x;
```

or

```
y = ++x;
```

---

See [Postfix increment and decrement operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Can you illustrate using _one_ variable, as in the question?

Comment: This behavior doesn't follow trivially from the definition of post-increment. In other languages such as C or C++ this expression would be undefined. It's only defined in C#, because the evaluation order is well defined.

Comment: I added an example using the original problem specified in the question, as suggested by @Oded.

Comment: @EricLippert:  You are right of cause. I clarified my statement.