# Behaviour of C# code

Tags: c#, post-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explaining post-increment in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863736/explaining-post-increment-in-c-sharp)

Consider the following C# code:-

```
int i = 2;
i = i++;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

I am getting the output as `2`. Why there is no effect of `i = i++`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java

Comment: This is the correct dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287839/c-sharp-increment-operator-questionwhy-am-i-getting-wrong-output

Comment: See its a confusing ques (Read Interview type). If = takes precedence first, then increment happens afterwards means i should be 3. If ++ takes precedence first then after incrementing it should assign 3 in i.

Comment: It will compiled into

    int i = 2;
    int topOfStack = i;
    i++;
    i = topOfStack;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you put the `+`-operators, the value assigned is incremented before or after:

```
i = ++i;
```

This way `i` is counted up before assigned.

```
i = i++;
```

This way `i` is counted up after assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `=` operator takes precedence first.

MSDN: [Operator precedence and associativity.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Try this one:

```
int i = 2;
i = ++i; // or write just ++i;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Yes it does. But it should increment i after, isn't it?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6716217/675462